# Why is bmp loading faster than png

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, bitmap, png

I have a sample wpf app here and wondering, why BMP is loading faster than PNG. Here is the exact setup:

```
- Windows 7
- Visual Studio 2013
- landscape.png, 1920x1080, 2.4mb
- landscape.bmp, 1920x1080, 5.6mb
- wpf-app, class MainWindow.xaml.cs constructor, no other code before
```

Code:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var Bitmap1 = new Bitmap("landscape.bmp");
long t1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

sw.Restart();
var Bitmap2 = new Bitmap("landscape.png");
long t2 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

So the BMP loads with around 6ms, the PNG needs 40ms.

Why is that so?

Comment: Did you run this in the debugger? Did you do a burn in? Those can all affect times. Also, it could be that the `Bitmap` class has to decode the png, whereas it can take the bmp for what it is.

Comment: To perform a serious testing you should setup a testing environment. Code has to burn-in, test has to be repeated multiple times and you MUST consider caches (in this case disk cache will play a huge role). After all has been done properly...you'll probably see a very small difference...png is much more complex and it has to be decompressed. It may takes some milliseconds (for an image big enough to measure this difference).

Comment: Check the speed of simply reading the file into memory - if it still shows a similar time difference then it could be related to file storage. If it loads twice as quickly, then the issue may be the decoding.

Comment: Check what that `Bitmap` class does. Pro for the PNG: there is lots less data to be read. Con: the decoding part may be written badly. We can't tell.

Comment: Please note also that your tests may be entirely irrelevant for your WPF application, because in WPF you would create a BitmapImage or a BitmapFrame from an Uri or a FileStream, instead of using the WinForms Bitmap class.

Comment: thanks for your replies. So yes, I used the debugger, but if I write the time into a file or start the .exe, it seems to make no difference. If I run the "new Bitmap()- Line several times, it make no difference. What is a "burn in"? And my question is: Is this the same on your maschines?

Comment: I would ask the same question, for me saving files of any format that is .bmp or .png etc is faster with MyImage.save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.bmp). Stream array for bmp are larger yet with Diagnostic tools, I noticed it takes too less memory :) and is much faster than saving with ImageFormat.png.
Why is it so?

Answer (score 6):

First, we need to understand how digital images are stored and shown, a digital image is represented as a matrix where each element of the matrix is the color of the pixel, if you have a grayscale image then each element is a uint8 (unsigned 8-bit integer) number between 0 and 255 and in some cases, it's an int8 (signed 8-bit integer) number between -128 and 127. if the element is 0 (or -128 in int8 version) the color is solid black and if the element is 255 (or 127 in int8 version) the color is solid white.

[image: Grayscale image representation]

For RGB images each element of the said matrix takes 24 bit or 3 Byte to store (one Byte for each color), a very common resolution for digital cameras and smartphones is 3264 x 2448 for an 8-megapixel camera, now imagine we want to save a 3264 row matrix where each row has 2448 element and each element is 3 Byte, we need about 24 MegaByte to store that image which is not very efficient for posting on the internet or transferring or most of the other purposes. That is why we should compress the image, we can go for JPEG which is a lossy compression method and that means we do lose some quality or we can choose a lossless compression method like PNG which will give us less compression ratio but instead we are not gonna lose quality.

[image: RGB image representation]

Whether we chose to compress the image or not, when we want to see the image, we can only show the uncompressed version of the image, if the image is not compressed at all, there is no problem, we show exactly what it is, but if it's compressed, we have to decode it first (uncompress it).

With all that being said, let's answer the question. BMP is a format for somewhat raw images, there is either no compression at all or much fewer compression techniques are used than PNG or JPEG but the file size is bigger. When you want to show a BMP image, because it's bigger, there is more data to read into memory, but when it is read, you can show it very faster because there is either no need for decoding or much less decoding is required, on the other hand when you want to show a PNG image, the image will be read into memory much faster but compared to BMP the decoding is going take more time.

If you have a very slow storage, BMP images will be shown slow.
If you have a very slow CPU or your decoding software is not efficient PNG images will be shown slow.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Just wanted to say I read it, so you did not write for yourself only. All makes sense, I was just surprised 6 years ago. Fortunatelly I work with backend for 90% of the time :)